# Will a StreamSubscription stay alive indefinitely if cancel() is not called?

Tags: dart

I have always made a habit to call cancel() on all StreamSubsciptions in Dart. But I am curious what happens if I don't. Will the stream cancel if the garbage collection cleans up the StreamSubscription?

Answer (score 0):

That depends.

Nothing happens *because* of garbage collection, that much is guaranteed.

The stream source, usually a stream controller, has a reference to the stream subscription (because it needs to push events to the subscription), so if the stream source isn't garbage collected, neither is the stream subscription.
And the subscription has a reference to the controller, so that it can pause or cancel. So either both are GC'ed, or neither.

If the stream is being fed by some external source, like an HTTP connection, a file being read, a running timer or a `ReceivePort`, something which pushes events to the stream source, then that will likely keep the source alive.
If the subcription is paused, and the controller uses that to disconnect from the external source (say, stop the timer, planning to start a new one when the subscription is resumed), then there might be nothing keeping the stream source alive, and then it *can* garbage collected when nothing else refers to it or the subscription.

In general, cancel your subscriptions. It's safer.